# javascript replace regex spaces and newlines

Tags: javascript, regex

how to replace spaces and newlines together with additional closing code `;` in javascript?

```js
function main(){
   var a = 'hello'
   console.log(a)
}

console.log(main.toString().replace(/[\n ]/g,''))
```

output

```js
functionmain(){vara='hello'console.log(a)}
```

I want

```js
function main(){var a='hello';console.log(a);}
```

Comment: Either `main.toString().replace(/[\n]/g,'')` or [minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify) may help you. But still not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: A regex will not be able to actually _parse_, i. e. _understand_ your script. There can be line breaks in your script that serve as  a separator between two expressions but there will also be other cases when they have no meaning at all. That is when they appear in the middle of an expression that would otherwise be syntactically incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is correct

```js
function removeSpaces(str){
        str = str.replace(/[\n]/g,';')
    let res = str.replace(/[\n ;]/g,(e, i)=>{
       switch(e){
         case ';':
           if(!'{:['.includes(str.substr(0, i).slice(-1))){
             return ';'
           }
        default:
          let arr = str.substr(0, i).split(' ')
          let lastArr = arr[arr.length - 1]
          // need space code
          if(['function','var','let','const'].includes(lastArr)){
             return ' '
          }
          return ''
        }
     })
    return res;
}
function main(){
   var a = 'hello'
   console.log(a)
}

let str = main.toString()
console.log(str.replace(/[\n ]/g,''))
let res = removeSpaces(str)
console.log(res) // function main(){var a='hello';console.log(a);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, I think this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/dGpsrM/1) can do the job:

```
/(?:(?<![\{\}])[\n]|([\{\}\;])(\n)|\b\s\B|\B\s\b|\B\s\B)/g
```

1- part one :

```
 (?<![\{\}])[\n] -> matches ending of statements without ;
```

2- part two:

```
 ([\{\}\;])(\n) -> matches newlines after { or } or ;
```

3- part three:

```
 \b\s\B|\B\s\b|\B\s\B ->match white spaces
```

```js
function main() {
    var a = "hello"
    console.log(a)
    return 1;
  }
  
const result = main.toString().replaceAll(
  /(?:(?<![\{\}])[\n]|([\{\}\;])(\n)|\b\s\B|\B\s\b|\B\s\B)/g,
  function (match, p1) {
    if (match === "\n") return ";";
    if (match === " ") return "";
    return p1;
  }
);

console.log(result);
```